# How to define custon action for EnterKey of Soft Keyboard for EditText?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext

I want to perform an action when user clicks `return key (EnterKey)` in focused `EditText`.
This is the only `EditText` in my fragment. My purpose is to get the text from that `EditText` and clear the `EditText` and wait for next Input.

Here is my code:

```java
...
addTodoEditText = rootView.findViewById(R.id.addTodo_EditText_FragmentTodo);
addTodoEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                doMyFunction(); //I wan't to do my work here.
                return false;
            }
        });
...
```

and this is my `EditText`:

```xml
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/addTodo_EditText_FragmentTodo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Add New Todo"
        android:lines="1"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:background="@drawable/checkbox_drawable"
        android:textAppearance="@style/textRegular"/>
```

How can I solve this issue? Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this condition:

```java
addTodoEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                doYourFunction();
                return true;
            }
        return false;
        }
});
```